# ORA 04088 Trigger Issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a trigger that I would like to populate the geometry column after an update or a new record is created. The trigger I have built is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SFS_TRIGGER 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON SPORTS_FACILITIES_STRATEGY 
BEGIN
  UPDATE sports_facilities_strategy
     SET GEOMETRY = MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,81989, MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(EASTING,
                                                                        NORTHING,
                                                                        NULL),
                                       NULL,NULL);

END;
```

however I keep getting the following error message:

> ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'GIS_ADMIN.SFS_TRIGGER'
>   ORA-06512: at "GIS_ADMIN.SFS_TRIGGER", line 2

I get that it is struggling around the time of the update  but I'm stuck! Any help/suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `update` in the trigger will re-fire the same trigger, so it will loop forever - the error is Oracle killing the loop. Are you actually intending to update every row in the table, or are you trying to set a single field in the row thats being inserted/updated?

Comment: Just the row that has been updated.

Comment: so should it have a 'FOR EACH ROW' in the statement?

Answer (score 3):

The update in the trigger will re-fire the same trigger, so it will loop forever - the error is Oracle killing the loop.

To just set the `geometry` field on the row that is causing the trigger to fire, you don't issue an update, you use the `:new` syntax to set the value. I think you want a `before` trigger though...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SFS_TRIGGER 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON SPORTS_FACILITIES_STRATEGY 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :NEW.GEOMETRY := MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,81989,
    MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(:NEW.EASTING, :NEW.NORTHING, NULL), NULL,NULL);
END;
/
```

... assuming `NORTHING` and `EASTING` are columns in the `SPORTS_FACILITIES_STRATEGY` table)

Which is similar to [this example in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#BCFDEHHE).

Comment: I get compiler errors when I try to build this, it doesn't like the colon at the beginning...

Error(5,17): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; indicator 

Error(6,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:     . ( ) , * % & - + / at mod remainder rem <an exponent (**)>    and or || multiset

Comment: @SteveC81 - I missed a colon in the assignment (`:=` not `=`) - updated the answer, sorry. (Rookie mistake!)

Comment: What if you were editing existing records? Would this work also?

Comment: Yes, the trigger applies for `insert` or `update`, which is what you had. If you explicitly set a value for `geometry` in the `insert` or `update` statement then it would be overwritten by the value the trigger assigns, but I assume you're not planning to do that.

Comment: I now get the following error: Row 174: ORA-04098: trigger 'GIS_ADMIN.SFS_TRIGGER' is invalid and failed re-validation

Comment: `show errors` will give you more detail in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer, or query `user_errors`. Nothing's jumping out at me. Wait, what are `easting` and `northing`, are they columns in your table? If so, prefix those with `:new.` as well.

Comment: 'Easting' and 'northing' are values that will either exist in the table and are tweaked as the data is moved, or will be new values added to the table

Comment: @SteveC81 - but they are column names?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle ORA-06512 was thrown because the you may be trying to insert a row in the trigger which had to fire before insert. The trigger was causing itself to fire over and over and get stuck in a loop.